# what is the purpose of #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] in mule esb

Tags: xml, web-services, mule

what is the purpose of #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] in mule esb??

Can some one explain me with an example.
When getting a response from a webservice to my mule esb. When i placed simple logger with #[payload] I am able to see some simple hashcode in the logs like @1b8353(but not the payload message xml). But when logged using #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] I am able to see payload xml being logged clearly. Can someone explain its purpose clearly ??

Please comment for further clarification!!!!

Answer (score 5):

`#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]` Will try and transform the payload to the given desired class. In this case a String.

Whereas logging just `payload` will log whatever the current payload representation is.

The method `payloadAs(Class<T> outpuTType)` is on the Message context class which in turn calls the `MuleMessage.getPayloadAs(Class<T> outputType)` I believe:

http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#getPayload(java.lang.Class)

> Will attempt to obtain the payload of this message with the desired
>   Class type. This will try and resolve a transformer that can do this
>   transformation. If a transformer cannot be found an exception is
>   thrown. Any transformers added to the registry will be checked for
>   compatibility Parameters: outputType - the desired return type
>   Returns: The converted payload of this message. Note that this method
>   will not alter the payload of this message *unless* the payload is an
>   InputStream in which case the stream will be read and the payload will
>   become the fully read stream. Throws: TransformerException - if a
>   transformer cannot be found or there is an error during transformation
>   of the payload